# MPI_Thread_init conflicts with window creation

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

I'm working on a project for which i need multiple threads in an MPI c++ program, i also need an MPI window, declaring the window with `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` makes the program exit without any error at the creation on the MPI window, if the value of requested threading is changed or removed completely (using only `MPI_Init`) the the window is normally declared and everything works correctly

```
int main(int argc, char *args[]){

int provided;

//freopen("log.txt", "w", stdout);

MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &args, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided);

int dim = 65532;
int num_proc;
int task_id;

if(provided != MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE){
    cerr << "ERROR ON THREAD INIZIALIZATION" << endl;
}

MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_proc);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &task_id);

MPI_Request req;
int* array = new int[dim];
int chunk_size = dim/(num_proc-1);
int* recv_buffer = new int[chunk_size];
int local_result = 0;
int global_result = 0;
int sendArray[num_proc];
int dispArray[num_proc];
bool sentFlag = false;
int *test_buffer = new int[100];

float local_average;
int threshold;

MPI_Win win;
MPI_Win_create(test_buffer, 100 * sizeof(int), sizeof(int), MPI_INFO_NULL,
                 MPI_COMM_WORLD, &win);

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if(task_id == 0){

    calculate_time();       
    cout << "PROBLEM DIMENSION : " << dim << " WITH " << num_proc-1 << " WORKERS" << endl;
    calculate_time();
    cout << "CHUNK SIZE : " << chunk_size << " PERCENTAGE : " << ((float)chunk_size/dim)*100 << "%" << endl;
    for(int i = 0;i<dim;i++)
        array[i] = 1;

    sendArray[0] = 0;
    
    for(int i = 1;i<num_proc;i++){
        sendArray[i] = chunk_size;
        dispArray[i] = (i-1)*chunk_size;
        }
    }
    
    calculate_time();
    cout << "PROCESSOR : " << task_id << " CALLING SCATTER..." << endl;
    MPI_Scatterv(array, sendArray, dispArray, MPI_INT, recv_buffer, chunk_size, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    local_average = chunk_size;
    threshold = 100;

    vector<int> vector_buffer(recv_buffer, recv_buffer + chunk_size);

    if(task_id == 0){
        matchmakerMainLoop(num_proc, &global_result, chunk_size);
    }else{
        calculate_time();
        cout << "PROCESSOR : " << task_id << " BEGIN REDUCTION" << endl;
        local_result = local_reduction(&vector_buffer, local_average, threshold);
        calculate_time();
        cout << "PROCESSOR : " << task_id << " COMPUTATION ENDED, GOING IDLE WITH RESULT : " << local_result << endl;
    }


    if(task_id != 0){
        MPI_Send(&local_result, 1, MPI_INT, 0, DATA, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        calculate_time();
        cout << "FINAL VALUE SENT!" << endl;
    }

    if(task_id == 0){
        calculate_time();
        cout << "PROCESS ENDED WITH RESULT : " << global_result << endl;
    }

    calculate_time();
    cout << "PROCESSOR : " << task_id << " CLOSING..." << endl;
    MPI_Win_free(&win);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I've made multiple tests with barriers, different buffers and declaration of MPI_Win and MPI_Win_Create but it only seems to work when thread support is removed, I could not find any information about problems with thread and RMA and other people seem to use them without any problems, I've also tried to change MCA's when executing but could not find any module that made a difference.
I'm using MPI 4.1.5

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Please don't deceive the reader with your indentation. It looks like the Scatterv call is inside `if(task_id == 0){`. 2. The ue of `new` is not good C++ style. Use containers. 3. What is your actual error?